# Как в датафрейме сравнить 2 столбца на наличие несовпадений более чем в 1 символ?

Tags: python, pandas, re

У меня есть датафрейм,
в нем есть `df['x']` - столбец и `df['y']` -  столбец.

В этих столбцах, в каждой строке содержится по 7-8 символов. Нужно найти те, где различий больше, чем в 1 символ.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Данные приведите в текстовом виде. зачем нам ваша фотография?

Answer (score 0):

1. Создаем функцию `more1()`, которая будет возвращать `True` только тогда, кода в 2 числах более чем 1 различие:

   ```
   def more1(num1, num2):
       str1 = str(num1)
       str2 = str(num2)
       differences = 0
       for digit1, digit2 in zip(str1, str2):
           if digit1 != digit2:
               differences += 1
               if differences > 1:
                   return True    # более чем 1 различие
       return False
   ```
2. Составим из ее NumPy *ufunc* (т.е. *универсальную* функцию, которая будет работать не только с 2 числами, но и с 2 *полями чисел*, потому что у нас 2 серии — столбцы `"x"` и `"y"`):

   ```
   import numpy as np

   ufunc_more1 = np.frompyfunc(more1, 2, 1)     # 2 вводные поля, одно выводное
   ```
3. Используем эту функцию для фильтрации (только тех строк датафрейма, в которых числа в столбцах `"x"` и `"y"` отличаются в более чем v 1 цифре):

   ```
   df[ufunc_more1(df.x, df.y)]
   ```

---

Вывод:

> ```
>              x             y
>  3    4619391067  4619391607
>  8    3616303322  3606561956
> 10    6316281671  6305855298
> 11    6018329898  6004097862
> 12    8703909750  4106946873
> 13    6715517863  7503830261
> 15    7115173235  7115173325
> 18    8409278501  8409278602
> 19    2518579547  2501584754
> 20     515346646   512996363
> 21    4618976289   411036170
> 22    4611501430  4611501403
> 27    7819398970  7814030634
> ```